# CSS tile border image left and right of div

Tags: css, border, border-image

I am new to using the border image property and I am not sure if this is actually the best approach for what I am trying to achieve. I would like to create a film reel style left and right border for an element that looks like this:
[image]

I am doing this in Bootstrap so one way may be just make the form a col-10, and then on the left and right do a col-1, however maybe there is a better way to do this using CSS.

I have tried to experiment with the border image property, however I am new to it so I have not had much success. The code below is what I have so far:

```css
.mainHeading {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: din-1451-lt-pro-engschrift, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.teammateHeader {
    background-color: #5ba676;
}

.teammateHeader .mainHeading {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.filmBorder {
    border-image-source: url('https://mathstory.org/img/filmSlice.svg');
    border-image-width: 0 90;
    border-image-outset: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/krg3ekk.css">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
<div class="container form filmBorder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 teammateHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
                    <h1 class="mainHeading">Submission</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 d-lg-block d-none">
                    <img src="https://mathstory.org/img/teammate.svg">    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: instead of a border, you could use padding and have a repeated background image

Comment: please let me know the correct image to check - img/filmSlice.svg

Comment: @Pete I like your approach, however it is not a responsive one, so I would have to media query it a bit, but it's quite a good idea mate.

Comment: if you add the repeating background to pseudo elements you can have one on either side and not need the padding as you can just absolutely position them outside

Comment: @Pete tried that and it worked like a dream. Really like this approach as I do not need to mess with the padding of the Bootstrap containers, meaning that I don't have the content smaller than usual. Post this as an answer and I will mark you correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `padding` *(class `px-5` for the example)*  and `background` / `background-size`:

possible example:

```css
.mainHeading {
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: din-1451-lt-pro-engschrift, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.teammateHeader {
    background-color: #5ba676;
}

.teammateHeader .mainHeading {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 100px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.filmBorder {
    background: 
    url('https://mathstory.org/img/filmSlice.svg') 0 0 repeat-y,
    url('https://mathstory.org/img/filmSlice.svg') 100% 0 repeat-y
    #000;
    background-size:2rem auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/krg3ekk.css">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  
<div class="container form filmBorder px-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 teammateHeader">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
                    <h1 class="mainHeading">Submission</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 d-lg-block d-none">
                    <img src="https://mathstory.org/img/teammate.svg">    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```